# Excel - What is the best way to analyse the following data?

Tags: excel, math, filtering, analysis

I'm looking for the best way to analyse the following data.

[image]

This is the amount in hours an employee has taken in a year and what remains. The data bars are a percent of hours taken from what they're allotted, shown in column K. Col I is how many hours they have left, and col J shows the cumulative holiday they've taken throughout the year.

I need the relevant info shown on one row where each row will be an employee's holiday history. Different employees have different hours and I need a way that shows who is in most need of taking holiday when that filtering from largest to smallest etc.

Where I find this tricky is if an employee had 10 hours allotted, and has taken 2 hours, that's 20%, which is the same if someone had 100 hours and has only taken 20 hours. But it's clearly more important that the second employee uses up some of their leave. I'm struggling with the best way to represent this.

Comment: Sounds like the difference between relative and absolute amounts.  Create a metric that weights individuals with larger absolute amounts more heavily when relative amounts are similar.  This is your artificial fitness function to assess need to take time off.  It can include whatever works for you.